# What type of grease to use as general purpose bearing lubricant?

Tags: maintenance, lubricant

Lithium grease, white litium grease, graphite grease, carbon grease, SRAM`s Liquid O-ring. And those are only the types of greases I have heard about.

What type of grease would be suitable for bearings like headsets, BBs, Shimano hubs?

Comment: Come on Liquid O-ring is for forks.  Carbon grease is for carbon components.

Comment: Your standard Valvoline multipurpose grease (e.g. for car wheel bearings) is something some people use. But really, the rest aren't for anything close to bearings.

Comment: I find my question question better, as in more focused on a single problem, than the linked duplicate!